# Unable to update NuGet packages Xamarin.Forms to v2.5 in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

I am using Windows 10 with Visual Studio Community 2017 (v15.5.6). Right now I'm trying to update NuGet packages for `Xamarin.Forms` from v2.3.4.231 to v2.5.

NuGet packages Xamarin.Forms updated successfully on Portable project and Xamarin.iOS project, but failed on Xamarin.Android. It keep rolling back to previous version and shows error message *"The Collection is read-only"*.

Thanks in advance for those who can point out my mistakes. :) Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, end-up I solve this with all this steps:

(1) First select a correct `Target Framework` for your project. For me, I target *Android Oreo*. And will be good if your project is supports latest Android SDK. Go to `Tools` -> `Android` ->  `Android SDK Manager` to check and install latest SDK.

[image]

(2) Before updates Xamarin.Forms 2.5, make sure certain NuGet packages in Android has up-to-date. For my case is I need to make sure packages `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design` has updated to version 25 or above.

[image]

(3) If you hit error message *"The Collection is read-only"*. Go to `Tools` -> `NuGet Package Manager` -> `Package Manager Settings` and click on button `Clear All NuGet Cache(s)`. After this, close Visual Studio -> go to your project folder -> delete all your `bin` and `obj` file -> start Visual Studio again.

[image]

(4) Okay, now you can update NuGet packages Xamarin.Forms to version 2.5. After update, clean and build project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a known issue with NuGet that happens sometimes and is caused by package cache and temporary files (see the [issue report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169526/nuget-get-error-this-collection-is-read-only-while.html) in VS Developer Community).

The solution is to go to `Tools` -> `NuGet Package Manager` -> `Package Manager Settings` and then click the `Clear All NuGet Cache(s)` button or use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> shortcut. Now close Visual Studio, navigate to your project folder and delete all `obj` and `bin` folders. Start Visual Studio again and everything should work properly now.

Comment: Manage to resolve error message "_The Collection is read-only_" by clearing caches, but it's still unable to upgrade NuGet packages Xamarin.Forms. Here is some log output regarding to the issues `Adding package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.26.1.0.1' to folder ''
Added package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.26.1.0.1' to folder ''
Install failed. Rolling back...`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - I went to update all packages on an old Xamarin solution that hadn't been touched for several months.

I got the

> "This collection is read-only"

message.

I realised I was running another instance of VS2017 for another project (and actually NuGet updating on that as well, although that may not be relevant).

I shut the other VS2017 down (and the Android emulator I'd been running, although I don't think that was relevant either).

I went through a couple of NuGet update cycles where VS2017 said something like

> The package at '...\packages\Xamarin.Forms.foo.bar.w.x.y.z' failed to uninstall.
>
> Restart Visual Studio to finish the process.

(but a different file each time)

I dutifully restarted each time and it finally came up squeaky clean with all the packages updated.